# Application of Aggregation and Composition

Tags: aggregation, composition

Ok, I understand Composition and Aggregation.

An aggregation is any object that can exist outside of the "parent" class. Composition means that when the parent dies, the objects it is composed of dies.

Ok, I have a testing application. A Category can have Videos. A Question can also have videos. A Category is made up to many Questions. I'm trying to figure out what would be the best model since both can have videos but they probably will not SHARE the same videos. Yet in some cases they may.

For the test taking use case, these videos are not watched apart from the Category or Question objects. So I could design them both as composing Videos members. I'm not sure if that is a good design. I could compose them in Category but provide them through a method to the Question object. In this case Question would be a sibling of Video member variable and would simply use it. This would be an aggregation.  However, all videos are not Category videos and all videos are not Question Videos. Sometimes they can be both.

By Category videos, I mean the user watches the video before taking the test. Thus the videos are on the category level but not the question level.

Question videos are videos that one watches and then answers questions regarding. In this scenario the video is more like a figure you look at and answer the question the best you can.

In some cases they can be both.

Is there a better way to design this?  Passing the videos seems like a lot of coupling that may not be necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an association class which can store the Video id, Associaton Type=Category/Question/Both, AssociateIds(a list)

In this case, you don't need to use Aggregation or Composition.